# Bounding an integral $\int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x-y|^{q}}\;dx$

Tags: integration

Let $q \geq 0$ be a real number. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Let $y \in \Omega$.

Can someone show me how to bound the integral as follows:
$$\int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x-y|^{q}}\;dx \leq C\text{diam}(\Omega)$$
where $C$ is a constant.

I cannot use the bound $|x-y| \leq const$ (because bounded domain) as $|x-y|$ is in the denominator..

**I Ask to understand this proof**:
[image]

How does he do the second inequality? In the picture, $p$ is positive integer and $s \in (0,1).$

Comment: @julien $q$ is fixed but the constant can depend on $q$. Are you sure it's an iff, please see my picture attached.

Comment: Just a trivial observation here: The problem is translation invariant, so you might as well let $y=0$. For bounded $\Omega$ the integral will be finite if and only if $q<n$.

Comment: Now that the problem has changed, let $y=0$ as I stated above and replace the integral by one over the ball of radius $R=\operatorname{diam}\Omega$. You get a constant times $\int_0^R r^{n-1-q}\,dr$ (the constant being the area of the unit sphere).

Comment: Yes, that's an iff $p(1-s)-N +N-1=p(1-s)-1>-1 \iff p(1-s)>0$. So you are fine: this converges in the pasted text. But as Harald Hanche-Olsen said: it is iff $-q+N-1>-1 \iff q<N$ in your initial question.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thank you!

Comment: @julien thank you for explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain is contained in a ball of radius $R$, you can do a change of variables and bounded it by
$$ \int_{|x|<2R} \frac1{|x|^q} \, dx $$
Change this using polar coordinates, and this becomes
$$ \int_0^{2R} \frac1{r^q} nw_n r^{n-1} \, dr $$
where $w_n = |B(0,1)|$.  Now if $q$ is small enough, say $q < n$, this is
$$ C (2R)^{n-q} .$$

Comment: So $C_R$ should be $nw_n$, it seems, and if we take a ball centered as our domain, it should show us that $C_R$ is sharp for a given $R$.